# How to get a solution to a puzzle having a function that gives the next possible steps in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm solving the [Brigde and torch problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_and_torch_problem)

in Haskell.

I wrote a function that given a state of the puzzle, as in which people have yet to cross and those who have crossed, gives back a list of all possible moves from one side to the other (moving two people forwards and one person backwards).

```
module DarkBridgeDT where


data Crossing = Trip [Float] [Float] Float deriving (Show)
data RoundTrip = BigTrip Crossing Crossing deriving (Show)

trip :: [Float] -> [Float] -> Float -> Crossing
trip x y z                  = Trip x y z    

roundtrip :: Crossing -> Crossing -> RoundTrip
roundtrip x y               = BigTrip x y


next :: Crossing -> [RoundTrip]
next (Trip [] _ _)              = []
next (Trip (a:b:[]) s _ )   
    |a>b                    = [BigTrip (Trip [] (a:b:s) a) (Trip [] [] 0)]
    |otherwise              = [BigTrip (Trip [] (b:a:s) b) (Trip [] [] 0)]
next (Trip d s _)               = [BigTrip (Trip [x,z] (i:j:s) j) b | i <- d, j <- d, i < j, x <- d, z <- d, x < z, z /= i, z /= j, x /= z, x /= i, x /= j, b <- (back [x,z] (i:j:s))]
    where
        back [] s           = []
        back d s            = [Trip (i:d) (filter (/= i) s) i | i <- s]
```

Now I need a function that given a state as the one above and a maximum amount of time gives back all possible solutions to the puzzle in less than that given time.

All I have for that is this:

```
cross :: Crossing -> Float -> [[RoundTrip]]
cross (Trip [] _ _) _               = []
cross (Trip _ _ acu) max 
    | acu > max                 = [] 
cross (Trip a b acu) max                = map (cross (map (crec) (next (Trip a b acu)) acu)) max
    where
        crec (BigTrip (Trip _ _ t1) (Trip a b t2)) acu  = (Trip a b (t1+t2+acu))
```

Of course that doesn't compile, the 5th line is the one that's driving me insane. Any input?

Edit:
The `cross` function is meant to apply the `next` function to every result of the last `next`function called.
If the first result of next was something like: `[A,B,C,D]` then it would call `next` on A B C and D to see if any or all of those get to a solution in less than `max` (A B C and D would be Crossings inside which contain the floats that are the time that ads up and is compared to max).

My data structure is

Crossing: Contains the first side of the bridge (the people in it represented by the time they take to cross the bridge) the other side of the bridge (the same as the other) and a time that represents the greatest time that last crossed the bridge (either the greatest of the two in the first crossing or the only one in the second) or the amount of time acumulated crossing the bridge (in the cross function).

RoundTrip: Represents two crossings, the first and the second, the one getting to safety and the one coming back to danger.

`cross (Trip [1,2,5,10] [] 0) 16` should give an empty list for there is no solution that takes less than 17 minutes (or whatever time unit).

`cross (Trip [1,2,5,10] [] 0) 17` should give the normal solution to the puzzle as a list of roundtrips.

I hope that makes it clearer.

Edit2:
I finally got it. I read Carsten's solution before I completed mine and we laid it out practically the same. He used fancier syntax and more complex structures but it's really similar:

```
module DarkBridgeST where

data Torch = Danger | Safety deriving (Eq,Show)
data State = State
   [Float] -- people in danger
   [Float] -- people safe
   Torch   -- torch position
   Float   -- remaining time
   deriving (Show)

type Crossing = [Float]

classic :: State
classic = State [1,2,5,10] [] Danger 17

next :: State -> [Crossing] -- List all possible moves
next (State []     _    _      _)           = []  -- Finished
next (State _        []   Safety _)         = []  -- No one can come back
next (State danger _    Danger rem)         = [[a,b] | a <- danger, b <- danger, a /= b, a < b, max a b <= rem]
next (State _        safe Safety rem)       = [[a] | a <- safe, a <= rem]


cross :: State -> Crossing -> State  -- Crosses the bridge depending on where the torch is
cross (State danger safe Danger rem) cross  = State (taking cross danger) (safe ++ cross) Safety (rem - (maximum cross))
cross (State danger safe Safety rem) cross  = State (danger ++ cross) (taking cross safe) Danger (rem - (maximum cross))

taking :: [Float] -> [Float] -> [Float]
taking [] d                         = d
taking (x:xs) d                 = taking xs (filter (/=x) d)

solve :: State -> [[Crossing]]
solve (State [] _ _ _)              = [[]]
solve sf = do
    c <- next sf
    let sn = cross sf c
    r <- solve sn
    return (c:r)
```

All in all thanks everyone. I'm new to Haskell programming and this helped me understand a lot of things. I hope this post can also help someone starting haskell like me one day :)

Comment: what are you trying to do there? (It's really hard to understand)

Comment: aside from my difficulties understanding your idea/algorithm there are several problems in that line: `map` wants a list as last parameter but you give it the `Float` `max`, ...

Comment: Yes, that line was meant to convey what I want it to do even if it was a disaster. I really can't see how to make a call to `cross` give a list of something when I finally want a list of lists of that something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to leave much of your code intact here.

The first problems are with the data structures. `Crossing` doesn't actually represent anything to do with crossing the bridge, but the state before or after a bridge crossing. And you can't use `RoundTrip` because the number of bridge crossings is always odd.

I'm renaming the data structure I'm actually keeping, but I'm not keeping it unmodified.

```
data Bank = Danger | Safety deriving (Eq,Show)
data PuzzleState = PuzzleState
  [Float] -- people still in danger
  [Float] -- people on the safe bank
  Bank -- current location of the torch
  Float -- remaining time
type Crossing = ([Float],Bank)
```

Modifying/writing these functions is left as an exercise for the reader

```
next :: PuzzleState -> [Crossing] -- Create a list of possible crossings
applyCrossing :: PuzzleState -> Crossing -> PuzzleState -- Create the next state
```

Then something like this function can put it all together (assuming `next` returns an empty list if the remaining time is too low):

```
cross (PuzzleState [] _ _ _) = [[]]
cross s1 = do
  c <- next s1
  let s2 = applyCrossing s1 c
  r <- cross s2
  return $ c : r
```

Comment: Crossing does represent a state, but having the former state I get the same result as an actual crossing. And I don't need to represent the torch since it's always going to be two people crossing to safety and one going back. It could even be done just moving one of the elements of the safe list to the other and adding the correct time as if two went and one came back.

Comment: the very last trip should not involve one going back ;) - personally I find this a very elegant description (although I would use record syntax to make it readable without the comments and to help me remember the parts ;) )

Comment: That's what I meant when I said `RoundTrip` didn't quite fit. I think it's possible to do it just by relying on the "two people cross to safety and one person crosses back" pattern, and it might even make the `next` function simpler but it would make the `cross` function more complicated.

Comment: You're both quite right. I'm now trying to complete Jeremy's solution and it looks way better and more elegant than mine. I'll let you know how it went and edit the answer if I get it.

Comment: in case someone wants the full *solution* I used Jeremys great proposal, tweaked it a bit and but it in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/CarstenKoenig/51060861b4ef5802bb43) ... but please mind the **spoilers**!

Comment: I'd also use this helper function in a couple of places if I were doing this on my own: `select [] = []; select (a:r) = (a,r) : map (\ ~(b,r') -> (b,a:r')) (select r)`, it's more efficient than using `delete`

Comment: @JeremyList yeah - efficiency was not my primal concern ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun, an approach using a lazy tree:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Tree

type Pawn = (Char, Int)

data Direction = F | B

data Turn = Turn {
  _start :: [Pawn],
  _end   :: [Pawn],
  _dir   :: Direction,
  _total :: Int
}

type Solution = ([String], Int)

-- generate a tree
mkTree :: [Pawn] -> Tree Turn
mkTree p = Node{ rootLabel = s, subForest = branches s }
  where s = Turn p [] F 0

-- generates a node for a Turn
mkNode :: Turn -> Tree Turn
mkNode t = Node{ rootLabel = t, subForest = branches t }

-- next possible moves
branches :: Turn -> [Tree Turn]
-- complete
branches (Turn [] e d t) = []
-- moving forward
branches (Turn s e F t) = map (mkNode.turn) (next s)
  where
    turn n = Turn (s\\n) (e++n) B (t+time n)
    time = maximum . map snd
    next xs = [x| x <- mapM (const xs) [1..2], head x < head (tail x)]
-- moving backward
branches (Turn s e B t) = map (mkNode.turn) e
  where
    turn n = Turn (n:s) (delete n e) F (t+time n)
    time (_,b) = b

solve :: Int -> Tree Turn -> [Solution]
solve limit tree = solve' [] [] limit tree
  where 
    solve' :: [Solution] -> [String] -> Int -> Tree Turn -> [Solution]
    solve' sols cur limit (Node (Turn s e d t) f)
      | and [t <= limit, s == []] = sols ++ [(cur++[step],t)]
      | t <= limit = concat $ map (solve' sols (cur++[step]) limit) f
      | otherwise = []
      where step = "[" ++ (v s) ++ "|" ++ (v e) ++ "]"
            v    = map fst
```

Then you you can get a list of solutions:

```
solve 16 $ mkTree [('a',2), ('b',4), ('c',8)]

=> [(["[abc|]","[c|ab]","[ac|b]","[|bac]"],14),(["[abc|]","[c|ab]","[bc|a]","[|abc]"],16),(["[abc|]","[b|ac]","[ab|c]","[|cab]"],14),(["[abc|]","[a|bc]","[ba|c]","[|cab]"],16)]
```

Or also generate a tree of solutions:

```
draw :: Int -> Tree Turn -> Tree String
draw limit (Node (Turn s e d t) f)
  | t > limit = Node "Time Out" []
  | s == []   = Node ("Complete: " ++ step) []
  | otherwise = Node step (map (draw limit) f)
  where step = "[" ++ (v s) ++ "|" ++ (v e) ++ "]" ++ " - " ++ (show t)
        v    = map fst
```

Then:

```
putStrLn $ drawTree $ draw 16 $ mkTree [('a',2), ('b',4), ('c',8)]
```

Will result in:

```
[abc|] - 0
|
+- [c|ab] - 4
|  |
|  +- [ac|b] - 6
|  |  |
|  |  `- Complete: [|bac] - 14
|  |
|  `- [bc|a] - 8
|     |
|     `- Complete: [|abc] - 16
|
+- [b|ac] - 8
|  |
|  +- [ab|c] - 10
|  |  |
|  |  `- Complete: [|cab] - 14
|  |
|  `- [cb|a] - 16
|     |
|     `- Time Out
|
`- [a|bc] - 8
   |
   +- [ba|c] - 12
   |  |
   |  `- Complete: [|cab] - 16
   |
   `- [ca|b] - 16
      |
      `- Time Out
```